# Define A Typescript Interface Where A Property Is An Existing Object's Properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the best way to define an interface where one of the properties could be any of the properties on an existing object. In this case I have an object called fruits where I am simply storing a number of string constants and I want to define an interface (groceries) such that one of the properties (fruit) could be any of the string constants in the fruits object.

```
type Fruits = 'APPLE' | 'BANANA' | 'ORANGE';

const fruits = {
    APPLE: 'APPLE',
    BANANA: 'BANANA',
    ORANGE: 'ORANGE'
}

interface IGroceries {
    fruit: Fruits,
    vegetables: string[]
}

const initialGroceriesState: IGroceries = {
    fruit: fruits.APPLE,
    vegetables: []
}
```

This is my best attempt but this will throw an error saying:

```
Type '{ fruit: string; vegetables: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IGroceries'.
  Types of property 'fruit' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fruits'.
```

Comment: simply: const initialGroceriesState: IGroceries = {
  fruit: 'APPLE',
  vegetables: []
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the options is switching to [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#string-enums):

```
enum Fruits {
    APPLE = 'APPLE',
    BANANA = 'BANANA',
    ORANGE = 'ORANGE'
}

interface IGroceries {
    fruit: Fruits,
    vegetables: string[]
}

const initialGroceriesState: IGroceries = {
    fruit: Fruits.APPLE,
    vegetables: []
}
```

Another option is correcting the typing of the existing object:

```
type Fruits = 'APPLE' | 'BANANA' | 'ORANGE';

const fruits: { [key: string]: Fruits } = {
    APPLE: 'APPLE',
    BANANA: 'BANANA',
    ORANGE: 'ORANGE'
}

interface IGroceries {
    fruit: Fruits,
    vegetables: string[]
}

const initialGroceriesState: IGroceries = {
    fruit: fruits.APPLE,
    vegetables: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fruits` key values are inferred to strings. This results in error, because `Fruits` is assignable to string type but not vice versa.

In order to avoid this, `fruits` type should be specified explicitly:

```
const fruits: { [K in Fruits]: K } = {
    APPLE: 'APPLE',
    BANANA: 'BANANA',
    ORANGE: 'ORANGE'
};
```

An another way is to use string enum, as another answer suggests. Depending on the case, this may or may not be desirable.